# I am unable to enable the google my business api

Tags: javascript, google-developers-console, google-my-business-api

I am trying to create a platform where users give us the consent to manage their account but when i am trying to list the account i am getting an error [![enter image description here][1]][1]

and when i am clicking on the link it will give an error [REDACTED]

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 403,
    "message": "Google My Business API has not been used in project 10318847845122525596215555558 before or it is disabled. Enable it by visiting https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/mybusiness.googleapis.com/overview?project=10318847845122525596215555558 then retry. If you enabled this API recently, wait a few minutes for the action to propagate to our systems and retry.",
    "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED",
    "details": [
      {
        "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.Help",
        "links": [
          {
            "description": "Google developers console API activation",
            "url": "https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/mybusiness.googleapis.com/overview?project=10318847845122525596215555558"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

and here is my tried code

```
<body>
    <h2>Infinity</h2>
    <div
      id="g_id_onload"
      data-client_id=""
      data-callback="handleCredentialResponse"
    ></div>
    <script>
      function handleCredentialResponse(response) {
        const config = {
          response_type: "permission",
          scope: "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.business.manage",
          client_id:
            "",
        };
        gapi.auth2.authorize(config, function (response) {
          console.log(response);

          var requestOptions = {
            method: "GET",
            redirect: "follow",
          };

          fetch(
            `https://mybusiness.googleapis.com/v4/accounts?access_token=${response.access_token}`,
            requestOptions
          )
            .then((response) => response.text())
            .then((result) => console.log(result))
            .catch((error) => console.log("error", error));
        });
      }
    </script>
  </body>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It appears that you have posted sensitive/private information. Please reset your passwords and/or revoke API keys and tokens, as they are considered compromised when posted on the internet.

Comment: I have deleted the client id

Comment: @singhAmardeep  sorry, had to redact the image.  Please update your post with a censored image  (or better yet) post it with just text

Comment: Is there any solution?